# Move rectangle towards another rectangle keeping the size the same

Tags: python, math, vector, rectangles

I have two rectangles *Rect1* and *Rect2* and I am trying to move *Rect1* towards the direction of *Rect2* but keep the size of the moving rectangle the same as *Rect1*.

```
Rect1 = {x1,y1,w1,h1}
Rect2 = {x2,y2,w2,h2}

diff = Rect2 - Rect1
new_vector = Rect1 + diff/2
```

The above formula was used.
I divided by 2, so the *new_vector* will be in the middle of the two vectors.
The *new_vector* is between the two other vectors but the size of it has increased, which is not what I want.
I am looking for another formula to keep the moving rectangle size the same as *Rect1*.

Thanks!!

Comment: This is not the actual code that I am using. I actually use NumPy arrays to implement that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but as I said, this is not my actual Python code. I use numpy arrays instead. I am not facing issues with the syntax, I am just trying to find a formula.

Comment: Okay.  I see.  It might be useful to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  Working code is generally preferred over pseudo code.  That said, when you calculate diff what do you think is happening to the 3rd and 4th elements of your numpy vector.  And then what is happening to those when you add it back to Rect1?

Comment: What do you mean by "moving towards  the direction of Rect2"? Moving it along the line that connects centers of the rectangles or something else? Note also that you have change only `x1` and `y1`.

Comment: Yes, moving it along the line that connects the centers of the rectangles, keeping w1 and h1 constant.